# SELECT IN statement doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to select with IN from mysql.
I have this query: `SELECT id, name FROM country WHERE id IN (2,1)`
If I run it from phpmyadmin I get two rows, but when I want to do it in a function I get just one row
This is my function

```
function search($res) {
    global $pdo;
    $arr = [$res];
    $in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM country WHERE id IN ($in)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($arr);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

What am I missing?
The problem seems to come from count($arr), gets back as 1.

Comment: can you show me what $in returns.i guess $in return only one $in

Comment: Hmm, $in is a ?

Comment: Can You var_dump($in) and post here?

Comment: `$arr = [$res];` is the same as `$arr = array($res)` as such `count($arr) - 1` will always = 0

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem

`$arr = [$res]` -> `$arr = explode(',', $res)`

I was getting all the elements of the array as the first and only element, I had to explode by comma to get the actual array.